# Excel VBA web resource download

Tags: excel, vba, cookies

I have the problem that I want to get a web resource inside of my Excel VBA.
The page from where I need the data is protected with Bearer and to factor auth.

To keep it simple, I want to open the page regular in EDGE and pass the complete auth stuff. If this is done, the plan is to use the VBA to get a resource with the received cookies.

The resource URI is something like this:

`GET https:\\service.mypage.com\stats\results`

The results is a JSON return.

How I can access the resource in the VBA and pass the existing auth cookies to the page?
Actually I receive only an error, that the auth information's are missed.

I found some answers to get a page, but they all don't have to pass cookies.

One of the examples is:

```
Dim hReq As Object, JSON As Dictionary
Dim strUrl as String

strUrl = "https:\\service.mypage.com\stats\results"

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        '-> how to add the auth cookie known by EDGE?
        .Send
    End With

'wrap the response in a JSON root tag "data" to count returned objects
Dim response As String
    response = "{""data"":" & hReq.ResponseText & "}"

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)

'process the data
```

Is there a way to get the cookies of a specific page from Edge and send them to the page?

Best regards
Björn

Comment: Have you tried to use the Selenium driver instead?